# Draw Canvas or Create Image File on .Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, canvas

I'm drawing my C# object model on controller and send it to `Konva.js` on the front end. And people can see my image as a canvas. No problem with these steps. Now I want to show my image on reports using `fastreport`. But I'm drawing canvas on runtime. How should I draw it on C# side and store it to show on reports?

```
//STAGE
Model obj = new Model()
{
           className = "Stage",
           attrs = new attrs()
           {
             height = 800,
             width = 1200,
             scale = new attrs()
              {
                x = zoom,
                y = zoom
               }
           },
            children = new List<Model>()
           {
                new Model()
                {
                    attrs=new attrs(),
                    className = "Layer",
                    children=a
                 },
           },
}
```

In short, I got a model like that. I want to draw it on C# side and use as an image file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved problem using base64string. I created base64string after konva's canvas create method. Saved base64string to database and when i want to use it on fast report, i converted to image file.